# Why i dont inject service in a angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, module, inject

i tried inject my service in mi controller, but not work and the chrome console show this error:

> angular.min.js:124 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/unpr?p0=bookServiceProvider%20%3C-%20bookService%20%3C-%20bookController

my html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  <script src="resources/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="services/book.service.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/book.controller.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-controller="bookController">

</body>
```

my controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('bookController', bookController);

bookController.$inject = ['$location', '$rootScope', '$scope', 'bookService'];

function bookController($location, $rootScope, $scope, bookService) {
    var vm = this;


}
})();
```

its to happen when i tried inject some library like toastr, other services etc...

Comment: You need to show the code where you are defining `bookService`, but Sébastien's answer is likely the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are defining your application module in your `book.controller.js` script

The following part creates a new module:

```
angular.module('myApp', []); // Creates and returns the "myApp" module
```

So I doubt that your `bookService` is declared in the same module.

If you already have a module named "myApp", then simply attach your controller to it:

```
angular.module('myApp'); // Returns a previously created module named "myApp"
```

Comment: thanks you!! I had defined the module within my service and in the controller!  now its work